# JMeter virtual user limits?

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, stress-testing

I want to do stress/load test for the payment process of an E-commerce app like "Flipkart" or "Amazon".

Will Apache JMeter be able to handle a load of 10,000 users and handle session keys since the users will be logging in through API calls?

Answer (score 3):

JMeter doesn't have limit of virtual users it can simulate, the number of virtual users you can mimic depends on several factors, to wit:

- Nature of your test (number of requests, request size, response data size)
- Number of [PreProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors), [PostProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions), etc.
- Machine hardware specifications
- etc.

So:

1. Make sure your test is developed and being executed according to [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. Make sure you monitor system resources utilization on JMeter machine using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)
3. Start your test with 1 virtual user and **gradually** increase the load to desired number of users you need to simulate at the same time keep an eye on system resources utilization. When any of monitored metrics (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk IO, etc.) exceeds reasonable threshold, i.e. 90% of maximum available capacity check the amount of active virtual users at this time via i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listeners - **this is how many users you can simulate using this machine and for this type of test**. If it is enough (10 000 or more) - you are good to go, if not - you will have to consider [running JMeter in distributed mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) i.e. add one more machine to run JMeter in clustered mode.

See [What’s the Max Number of Users You Can Test on JMeter?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what%E2%80%99s-the-max-number-of-users-you-can-test-on-jmeter) article for more detailed explanation if needed.